# working drupal website, show installation page again?

Tags: loops, drupal, installation, openshift

I'm in a weird situation, my drupal installation on openshift stopped working after a git push(I've been doing git push on this server for weeks and it was woking fine). It just shows the installation profile page as if i was setting up a new website. But when I enter back the info (i.e database name, password etc) it tells me that there is an existing website and shows me the link, but when i click on it, it goes back to the installation profile page.

I have checked on the server all my files from previous website seems to be there...

help plzzz....

Comment: Please make sure it is not a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check and make sure that your DB is intact. You can do that by sshing into your gear and logging into mysql with `$ mysql` and then running `SHOW DATABASES;` to confirm that your DB is still there. If it is you could go a few steps further to check the tables with `SHOW TABLES FROM drupal;`

Comment: when you ssh into your gear `rhc ssh <your appname>` and go `~/app-root/runtime/repo` what do you see in that directory?